# A check with the spelled out amount left out

Tags: banking

I received a check with the amount filled in as a number say $2000 but the spelled out portion (which should have been "Two thousand and 00/100") left blank. This was an oversight by the sender (out of state).

Question is can I spell out that number myself? Is that legal and acceptable to the bank? Instead of sending the check back to the original check writer I want to fill in the blank. Is it acceptable?

Comment: I saw that. But my q is about filling out that portion yourself not the original check writer

Comment: Look at this answer to that question: https://money.stackexchange.com/a/24043/22266