# Is it valid to write check without numeric amount but with words amount?

Tags: check, personal-check

I sent out a personal check with only words spelling out the check amount but I forgot to fill in the numeric amount in the box. Will my check get cashed in this way ?

Comment: which country it is ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it valid to write check without numeric amount but with words amount?

It appears so.  From from [the accepted answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/3282/22266) to [the exact opposite question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/3278/is-it-valid-to-write-checks-without-spelling-out-the-amount?rq=1):

> The Uniform Commercial Code section 3 covers negotiable instruments.

[§ 3-114](https://www.law.cornell.edu/ucc/3#s3-114). CONTRADICTORY TERMS OF INSTRUMENT

> If an instrument contains contradictory terms, typewritten terms prevail over printed terms, handwritten terms prevail over both, and **words prevail over numbers**.

To your other question:

> Will my check get cashed in this way ?

It should, but the teller might not know the law, or the bank might have a policy to reject such checks.

To be safe, I'd contact the people you wrote the check to.

Comment: I think your last sentence is key. The recipient of the check could just write the numbers into the blank field too, especially if the check writer gives them permission to. (I once had a client mail me a check, then call me because she realized she forgot to sign it, and asked me to forge it for her, using her signature from our contract as a guide.)

Answer (score 1):

Anything left "Blank" on a check is a Defect. Any Defect can cause the bank to reject the check. A teller can reject cashing a check with a defect. A check can be rejected after it have been deposited and the amount can be voided or removed from the account that it was deposited into. In effect a Defect can cause a Check to Bounce. This has happened to me, when a Tenant "forgot" to fill in the Numeric Amount on a check, even though the written amount was filled in.